# Imbalanced dataset in .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a dataset in `.csv` format that contains acoustic features that I will use for Gender Voice Recognition to predict which gender it is based on the dataset.

My problem is the dataset that I have `25 samples of females` and `152 samples of males`. In total: `177 samples (or rows)`.

This will cause me problems when I use an algorithm to train on the data.

My question is, How do I balance the ratio between male and female? How do I `ignore` or reduce the number of samples of males from `152 to 25` so that the ratio can be `1:1` between male and female? So that I have 25 female samples and 25 male samples.

Is there any method I can use?

example of my csv file:

```
> 1 - female
> 
> .
> 
> 25 - female 
> 
> 26 - male
> 
> .
> 
> .
> 
> .
> 
> 177 - male
```

The code is in `python`.

Comment: why don't you randomly select 25 samples of males and then do the analysis with 25 males and 25 females ?

Comment: How can I do this? Is there any way you could show me or explain?:)

Comment: Yes but I need more information about your file. The females are always in the rows 1 to 26? It's only one file? Do you use `pandas` to read the `csv` file?

Comment: Yes correct I use pandas. And there is always just females from row 1 to 26. Note that I also have header in the file

Comment: Okay I am writing an answer now

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

### Use `pandas.DataFrame.sample`.

If you have loaded the file using pandas then you would have something like this:

**Example:**

```
# 177 samples = 177 rows, with females in rows 1 to 25
df.shape 
(177,1)

# define a subset containg all the males data
males_all = df.loc[26:,:]

# randomly sample this and get 25 samples of MALES
sampled_males = males_all.sample(n = 25, random_state=0)

print(sampled_males.shape)
(25, 1)
```

Comment: I get an error saying "tuple object is not callable"

Comment: Which part of the code gives you this error? Can you upload the `csv` file ? Or a sample of it ?

Answer (score -1):

How about creating a dataframe of the male voices, then using [df.Sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to get 25 samples.

Or even better, if you create two dataframes, males_DF and females_DF, you can do something like:

```
sample_size = min(len(males_DF),len(females_DF))
male_sample_DF = males_DF.sample(sample_size)
female_sample_DF = females_DF.sample(sample_size)
```

(not tested, might need some changes)